# How does Software Center determine what is a "technical item" and what isn't?

Tags: software-center, packaging, deb

I'm a total newb to packaging, but I managed to get a PPA set up and working. But when I look for my software in Ubuntu Software Center, it will only show up after clicking "Show _ technical items". My software is not a technical item. How do I convey this information to the Software Center so it can appropriately categorize it?

I ship a .desktop file and it shows up in the menu perfectly. Software Center even lists the path to the menu entry after I install it ("Find it in the menu: ...").

EDIT: I spent some time on various Ubuntu IRC channels, and from conversations with a couple different people, the consensus seems to be that there is no way to fix this issue (and a couple others, such as showing an icon) for PPA packages. The way things are now, packages have to be in the main repos to fully integrate with Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 5):

Technical packages are ones that don't show up in the user menus.  That is, if you package ships a .desktop file, it will be considered non-technical.

Comment: But I do ship a .desktop file and it shows up in the menu perfectly. Software Center even lists the path to the menu entry after I install it ("Find it in the menu: ...").

Comment: Well, PPAs were supposed to be for techie users, but they became so popular... :P

Comment: That's true. They became popular for good reason, though. For instance, I'm preparing to make my first release of my software, which is a game targeted at a general audience, not just techies. It's much easier to put up a PPA and get some users than it is to get it accepted into the main repos before I actually have any users. I guess I could just put a .deb up on my website (which I will do in addition to a PPA), but PPAs give autoupdating for free, which is very nice.