# Full Apps Directory not available in Software Center

Tags: software-center

Can anyone tell me what depository I'm missing? If I search for say "Apache" at apps.ubuntu.com it comes up with what I'm looking for, if I search for it in the Software center all it comes up with are books and maybe some games.  Right now it looks like it's using the following sources:

http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Thank you,
David

Comment: Do you see the "show technical items" link at the bottom? http://askubuntu.com/q/83672/570

Comment: I see "Turn on Recommendations" but that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

After searching for apache you are likely shown a page like this:

[image]

At the bottom you see a button `Show .. technical items`. Click that and you should be presented with what you want.
[image]