# How to uninstall these Parole plugins

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, plugins

I'm using Xubuntu and while playing a YouTube video in Parole it said 'Parole needs text/html decoder to play this file' (I was pasting the link in Parole) I installed the asked plugins but still the video doesn't played. I then checked its plugins but they were not there. I'm in doubt if the plugins actually installed or not. They are also not appearing in Software Center. Here is a screenshot of what I've installed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm concerned about this because I don't want even a single crap in my OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 'plugins' are really just normal packages, hidden from the default software center view because they are deemed *technical items* – basically anything that's not a program is considered technical and thus hidden (according to [this answer here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55130/how-does-software-center-determine-what-is-a-technical-item-and-what-isnt)).

You can have the software center show technical items – and thus the packages you're looking for – by searching for their name and clicking the *Show x technical items* text in the lower left corner of the program windows.

If you don't want to bother with searching for each package and clicking the link,

`sudo apt-get purge libgnomecanvas2-common libgstbuzztard libgnomecanvas2-0 gstreamer0.10-buzztard libbml0 libbuzztard0 buzztard-data`

will remove all packages and their configuration at once.

As a general note: Since those packages are mostly libraries, they won't slow down your machine or do any harm to it other than occupying a few kB of your HDD space.